# Scanning worksheet in Excel and rounding in .5 increments

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large collection of data points in Excel that go to the first decimal place, and I need to scan through the data and have it round all values to .5 increments.  ie: if its 10.1 it should be 10.0 and if its 10.3 it should be 10.5.  Also I want it to paste the entire row on a seperate sheet with the new rounded number.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So, if a row contains a number that the sub has rounded to the nearest .5, you want to write that row  to a separate sheet, but not the rows in which no rounding was done? (PS: This possibly can be done with formulas.)

Comment: use mround(value,desired multiple)

Comment: thanks, but I ran into an issue with the mround.  I have both positive and negfative values and it only worked on the positive.  Is there an easy solution to handle this?

Comment: Basically you have to check for -1 make it a positive number then multiply by -1 after the check, otherwise you have to use -.5 in all instances of - numbers, which defeats teh purpose of using the formulas... so, we modify the formula... =MROUND(IF(B13<0,B13*-1,B13),0.5)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about copying the whole row to a separate sheet... but here's a few possible methods:

In sheet 1 I have formula's for random numbers with a few decimals
[image]

In sheet2 I use mround to round to the nearest .5

[image]

In sheet 3 I use a formula to get the values where rounding occurred. (but not the whole rows.  I didn't understand your data layout so I was unsure of what needed to be copied.

[image]

To solve negative number issues...  the problem is when using mround if the value being rounded is negative, the system forces you to use a negative decimal value.  Since in this case you don't know which values are positive or negative, you have to convert them all to positive (I suppose ABS would work as well) and then check to see if the original was negative and then multiply by -1 if it was.

=MROUND(IF(Sheet1!A2<0,Sheet1!A2*-1,Sheet1!A2),0.5)*IF(Sheet1!A2<0,-1,1) on sheet 2's formula.

Comment: I was able to use mround and it worked for half of my data, but my data has positive and negative values.  It didnt work on the negative values at all so I'm thinking should I write a short VBA program that first checks to see if negative then takes the absolute value, analyzes it, then converts it back to negative?  I'm not sure how to best handle this.

Comment: Best is a bit subjective, any method that doesn't add too much overhead is a good one if it works.  abs or checking to see if it's negative ... either way.  abs is simpler and ockham's razor says simpler of the two is "better" so I'll go w/ ABS :D